# swf can't load a local xml file in extendscript scriptui

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, extendscript

I created a swf file using actionscript 3.0 in flash builder. And I want to use this swf file in a after effects script(which is extendscript).

1. Now, my swf file need to load a xml file from a relative path. If I
   export the swf file from flash builder as a debug version, then load
   the swf file in the scriptui, I can load the xml file.
2. But, if I move the swf (debug version) to a different location (the relative path
   for the xml file is still right), I can't load the xml file anymore.
3. If I export the swf file as publish version, then I can't load the
   xml file no matter where I keep the swf file.

I'm using the "./sample.xml" style path and "URLLoader" and "URLRequest" to load the xml file.
Can anybody help me with this? I really appreciate it!
Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to the XML as absolute just to be sure it's not related to how the path is being interpreted at runtime?

Comment: agree to the above :)

Comment: I tried absolute path, didn't work either.I'm new to flash builder and action script, is there any security setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the security settings of the published SWF (I believe to access remote files only).